# Gradient glowing object - how to?

Tags: light

[image]

I need to create a sphere, which emits lights, which affect to other objects.
But the problem is: i need sphere to look like on the picture - center is always with one color and edges are glowing with another.
And this should not affect color of light.

I'm very new to Blender. I understood how to emit light that affects other objects. But it's white.

The important note is: it must be fully exportable, because i'm going to use it in another engine.

Sorry for any mistakes in sentences, please.

Comment: What other engine are you exporting to? What rederer are you using or trying to create this in? Materials are generally not very exportable, especially to other engines or applications, they are inherently very tied to the system they were created in, without any further info I doubt you can get any useful answer here.

Comment: I export it to the Unity

Answer (score 4):

Where exactly are you trying to export to and through which exchange format?
As stated above materials are very tied to the rendering system they were created for, you can't really export them as you can with a 3D model.

If you are using Cycles render you need to

1. Create a new material
2. Add two emission shaders (one with the desired color, the other white)
3. Use a *Mix Shader* node to mix them
4. Add a layer weight node as mixing factor
5. You may use either Fresnel or Facing as output
6. Optionally you can fine tune the color grading with a *Vector Curve Node*
7. To get the material to emit light only in one color add a new *Mix Shader* node
8. Connect the original shader to the bottom socket
9. Connect the uniform emission color to the top socket
10. To control that mix shader add a *Light Path* node
11. Connected the *Is camera* socket to the mix factor

[image]

This should work in Cycles, but as stated above it is very much tied to the way Blender works and how Cycles builds it's shaders, I very much doubt you will be able to export this anywhere useful, much less to a real time rendering system like a game engine or something.

Comment: I export it to Unity. I'm not sure that Cycles are work then..

Comment: I have never worked with Unity, but you will most likely have to create your material there, not in Blender.