# Is there a way to make emission shaders look less flat in cycles?

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders, emission

[image]

Im creating an exhibition scene, but the lights that I use look flat and strange in the scene. Is there any way to make them more detailed?

Comment: Same way you make anything look less flat.  Give them some kind of displacement.  Noise texture into a bump map or actual displacement in the geometry of the globals, for example.

Comment: Can you show the material setup? 
Did you use an emission shader? Have you tried using the principled shader with an "Emission Strength" value less than 1.0?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166425/blacklight-cfl-bulb-effect https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51172/gradient-glowing-object-how-to

Comment: mix it with a Diffuse node?