# Car led lights with gradient from center

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, emission

Is it possible to make an emission gradient from the centre of my car led lights?

I found out that the lights are more realistic that way but I can't figure out how to do it.
I searched tutorials on youtube but it doesn't work on flat surfaces or curved ones.

At this time I'm trying to fake it by making emission maps in photoshop but they don't look that good. I feel like the lights in my render look flat.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That 3rd picture in particular is going to be easier with a Glare node in the compositor

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51172/gradient-glowing-object-how-to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166425/blacklight-cfl-bulb-effect https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102534/emission-shader-that-glows-on-the-center-of-the-object-and-is-dark-on-the-edges